# How to avoid primary key column duplication in PostgreSQL v 10?

Tags: postgresql-10

I am running a script to update a table structure, my problem is with the primary key column (id), the query creates a new id column each time I run my script.

This the first time that I am trying to write a script to update a database structure.
The database was created by an old version of an application,and now we want to release a new version of the application, but to achieve this goal I wrote a script which in summary is creating tables if they don't exist, adding columns to the tables if they don't exist, deleting old indexes and creating the new ones, etc.

The problem happens when the scripts add the primary key in the tables, in the database, the tables have a primary key column of type integer. But my query is not detecting this primary key column and it creates a new column with the same name and data type, at least that is what I see in PGAdmin v4.8.

Originally the primary key columns were created using the type serial and then PostgreSQL automatically creates a sequence and use it for the primary key.

How can I avoid the duplicated primary key columns?

Originally the column was created like follows

```sql
create table mytable(
id serial,
.
.
.
);
```

And if I look in the table, the column looks like this, which means that PostgreSQL created a sequence mytable_id_seq and used it for the auto increment value of primary key column.

```sql
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('mytable_id_seq'::regclass)
```

But after I execute the following query and look in the table, it has a new column with the same name and data type like the one in the previous lines.

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.mytable ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS id serial;
```

I am expecting to see only one column no matter how many times I execute the query.

Comment: That `alter table` will most definitely not add a second `id` column to the table: https://rextester.com/JRSWV35129

Comment: what I think is that the column exits as integer type in the table and the alter query is trying to detect it as serial type and that's why my query fails.

Of course I am just guessing, maybe I am totally wrong or PGAdmin4 has a bug.

I think PostgreSQL stores the table definition in another place. But your are right the select query doesn't show a multiple `id ` columns

Comment: `serial` **IS** an integer [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) "*The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns*"